# Can you assign your own name to bookmarks or favorite places with Ubuntu?

Tags: bookmarks

Can you assign your own "name" to pages you bookmark or put into favorites on Ubuntu?
For example, say I'm on the Dodge Ram Trucks "build & price" web page and I want to add it to bookmarks for future use. Instead of the bookmark automatically being named "Dodge Trucks/build & price" etc., can I assign my own name for it like "Cars - Dodge Trucks"?
I'm used to assorting my favorite places on AOL this way and want to know if I can do similar on Ubuntu if I switch systems.

Comment: What do you mean wuth ubuntu bookmarks? You mean browser bookmarks? Ubuntu comes with Firefox installed and you can use plenty of other browsers like chromium/chrome/opera, etc.

Comment: If you are using the default browser, Firefox, you can rename your bookmarks to whatever you want.

Comment: You could bookmark in the way you want in any browser. Actually, bookmarking thing is not a platform dependent. It's up to browser. If you have got used to work on firefox in Windows and bookmarking, you could do the same way on firefox in Ubuntu either.

Comment: Thank You for your replies here... and yes - I would be using Firefox with Ubuntu. My apologies for lack of general knowledge on the topic... but Internet Exploder/AOL is the only system I've ever used!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Firefox as your default browser, simply right-click on your website of choice and use `Bookmark This Page` from the pop-up menu.

A dialog window/pop-up, like in the screenshot below appears, where you can change/put a custom name for the site you are about to add to your bookmarks.

- **Name**:   Put in your custom name
- **Folder**: Make sure you choose *"Bookmarks Toolbar"*

[image]

After that is done you additionally can choose `Bookmarks` from the Main-menubar and choose `Show All Bookmarks` - see 2nd screenshot.

[image]

From there you are able to further customize all of your bookmarks, ▸ like grouping, renaming, changing url(s), separating bookmarks with separators etc..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The steps are browser dependent, but every browser I've ever used (since 1990) lets me rename a favorite or bookmark.  Whether you're using Firefox, SeaMonkey, Chromium, or Google Chrome, there's a way to change the name of a bookmark --

Comment: How is "Yes" not an answer?

Comment: My apologies, but I would add a comment: It is browser-dependent, please add your browser and then answer with a specific, repeatable answer (you're dealing with a reputation 1 user, so they need a little bit more patience)  Mine is just a vote, so don't worry yet, until 2 other moderators vote the same way as me...

Comment: I read the question as "I haven't switched to Ubuntu yet" -- so they probably don't know what browser.  That would turn "You can certainly do what you want after you switch" to "we aren't sure how to answer your basic yes-or-no question".

Comment: :D :D :D We'll see what the OP says...  My vote for removal has been removed...  I bow (for the moment) to your wisdom! ;-)